# How to solve BinaryFormatter Deserialize 3th party object Exception in C#?

Tags: c#

In my project, I have a function which is used for loading objects from files:

```
public static ObjectBase LoadObject(string _filePath, string _name)
{
    ObjectBase module = null;

    try
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        Stream streamRead = new FileStream(_filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);

        object ob = formatter.Deserialize(streamRead);
        module = (ob as ObjectBase);
        streamRead.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
    }
    return module;
}
```

Everytime when I run this function, I hit exception:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
 at Cognex.VisionPro.Implementation.Internal.ccComFactory.CreateInstance()
 at Cognex.VisionPro.FGGigE.Implementation.Internal.CogAcqFifoGigE._com()
 at Cognex.VisionPro.FGGigE.Implementation.Internal.CogAcqFifoGigE..ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)

 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

 at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.SerializationInvoke(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext& context)
 at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.CompleteISerializableObject(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
 at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.FixupSpecialObject(ObjectHolder holder) at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups()
 at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
 at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
 at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
 at My code file.

Message: "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object." Source: "Cognex.VisionPro.FGGigE" StackTrace:
 at Cognex.VisionPro.Implementation.Internal.ccComFactory.CreateInstance()
 at Cognex.VisionPro.FGGigE.Implementation.Internal.CogAcqFifoGigE._com()
 at Cognex.VisionPro.FGGigE.Implementation.Internal.CogAcqFifoGigE..ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
```

Anyone have ideas? I really appreciate your helps!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The error occurs when trying to create an instance of the type `CogAcqFifoGigE`. Do you have access to source code of this type? Can you share code of the method `ccComFactory.CreateInstace`?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when trying to load vpp file (cognex) using this code line..

```
cogJobManager = CogSerializer.LoadObjectFromFile(jobFilesPath) as CogJobManager;
```

the solution for me was to uncheck the "Prefer 32-bit" from the project properties under Build tab, and compile it as Any CPU

after that the problem was solved